# image's delete button does not work

Tags: php, image, delete-file

i've made a php form input for delete image from a folder in my admin so my images are displayed but when i click on delete button it return me a blank page, and if i refresh my page the image i tried to delete is still here,

this is my code, what's wrong on it ?

```html
<?php
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }

}

?>

<?php
$dirname = "../img/travaux/villa/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img class="show-img" src="'.$image.'" />';
echo '<form class="delete-button" method="post">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$image.'" name="delete_file" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete image" />';
echo '</form>';
}

?>
```

and this is my upload image script:

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
 require("imgClass.php");
 $img = $_FILES['file'];
 $ext = strtolower(substr($img['name'],-3));
 $allow_ext = array("jpg",'png','gif');
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "../img/travaux/villa/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
  echo($_POST['index']);
 Img::creerMin("../img/travaux/villa/".$img['name'],"../img/travaux/villa/mini/",$img['name'],280,200);
 exit;
}
else{
 $erreur = "votre fichier n'est pas une image. !!attention renommer le .jpeg en .jpg";
}
?>
```

Comment: are you using absolute paths? does 'file_exist()` evaluate to true? What's the output of the script?

Comment: actuallly no, this all my code, i have a script for upload images but it is not in relation with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path the the images:

```
// get the absolute path
$dirname = realpath("../img/travaux/villa/");
```

Comment: my images are not display if i put realpath :/

Comment: only use realpath for `unlink()`, to display the images, the need to be relative to the document root, not absolute paths.

Comment: i' m actually in local server so why my page is returning a blank page and the image is not delete ? and my image folder is out of the admin folder but i think it change nothing

Comment: is your `error_reporting` on, and `display_errors`?